# Unity Web Player Fatal Resolution Error

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, resolution

I am trying to play an online game, namely [BeGone](http://www.nplay.com/BeGone/) on Windows XP in VirtualBox. After the game loads I get a fatal error notification that says, `Couldn't switch to requested monitor resolution`.

BeGone runs on [Unity Web Player](http://unity3d.com/webplayer).

The resolution is set to 1366x768 in XP. My actual host OS is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: Are the VirtualBox Guest Additions installed?